# last_insert_rowid() в sqlite3 возвращает 0 вместо id

Tags: python, sqlite3

sqlite3 возвращает ноль (или нули если написать FROM table_name). Я жду id, строку, но никак не 0.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT last_insert_rowid()") 
post = cursor.fetchall() # [(0,)]

cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages_table")
result = cursor.fetchall() # [(8,)]
```

Сама таблица:

```
"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages_table(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
messages_content_type TEXT NOT NULL,
messages_content TEXT NOT NULL)""")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел ответ. 
`cursor.execute("SELECT last_insert_rowid()` 
работает только если перед ним был в том же подключении была инструкция `insert`, иначе 0.